# Commutativity of ring $R$ necessary for $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,M')$ being an $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Why do we need $R$ to be commutative if we want $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,M')$ (where $M$ and $M'$ are $R$-modules) to be an $R$-module itself?

I tried to find out which axiom for modules does not hold if $R$ is not commutative but did not get any result.

Comment: How do you want to define the action?

Comment: $(r \cdot f)(x) = rf(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity is not satisfied:
$$(rf)(ax)=r\Bigl(f(ax)\Bigr)=r\Bigl(af(x)\Bigr)=(ra)f(x)\neq a\Bigl((rf)(x)\Bigr)=(ar)f(x),$$
unless $ar=ra$ for all $a,r$.